# How does Android application framework communicate with Libraries?

Tags: android

From Android architecture,  application framework (Content Providers,Resource manager. etc) are written in Java. But the libraries(Surface Manager, 3D libraries etc) are in C.

How do these layers communicate between to give the final output?

Comment: you should revisit some of your old answers and accept them if they have helped you.

Comment: There is no single answer, just as there is no single answer for many combinations of operating systems and programming languages.